# Jupyter shows plot without plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I am using the Jupyter notebook with Python 2.7. Importing matplotlib like this:

```
%matplotlib inline    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But I have observed one thing. When I use Python in Spyder I always have to use the `plt.show()` command at the end of the python script in order to see the plots.

In Jupyter I do not need this command in order to see a plot. I do get this error message:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x91615d0>]
```

but it still makes a plot. Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You turn on the immediate display with `%matplotlib inline`.

The line:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x91615d0>]
```

is no error message. It is the return value of the last command. Try adding a `;` at the end of the last line to suppress this.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Thanks. Fixed my typo.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement of adding `%matplotlin inline` is no longer needed in the latest jupyter notebooks. It's a by default addition now.

You can change settings in `ipython_kernel_config.py` for different behaviour

Comment: where is that file located?