# demo.py not show any pictures

Tags: python, caffe

I use python to test faster rcnn demo.py with windows cpu without cuda.In demo.py,there has a plt.show() at the end,but when I run demo.py, it didn't show any pictures.please see follows:

```
I0302 21:17:53.209992  1168 net.cpp:774] Copying source layer drop7
I0302 21:17:53.209992  1168 net.cpp:771] Ignoring source layer fc8
I0302 21:17:53.209992  1168 net.cpp:771] Ignoring source layer prob


Loaded network C:\Users\shihaohou\Desktop\py-faster-rcnn-              master\data\faster_rcnn_models\ZF_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Demo for data/demo/000456.jpg
Detection took 3.637s for 300 object proposals
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Demo for data/demo/000542.jpg
Detection took 3.580s for 300 object proposals
```

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398940/jupyter-shows-plot-without-plt-show) or similar questions?

Comment: yes,but it doesn't help. I find when I print bbox, it is no output information, so I  guess it maybe without data.To my surprised,the faster rcnn demo has all demo pictures and models,the question is why it is no data?