# Jupyter Notebook _repr_png_ returning Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

My current project requires a lot of evaluation. For convenience, I wrote a data class with Jupyter Notebook representations. My intention was to output different indicators as text (for copy & paste) and a boxplot as it is more descriptive in some cases.

[image: Jupyter Notebook Output]

To my surprise, (only) not calling `show()` or `close()` worked. However, this feels hacky to me. Thus my question: **Is this behaviour intended? And why does it work?**

To clarify what I'm wondering about, I expected this to happen regardless of calling `show()` or not:

[image: Output when calling show]

I know, I could simply add a `plot` method to the data class and call that, but this really interests me.

---

*Simplified version of the code:*

```
class EvaluationResult:

    def __init__(self, indicators, errors):
        self.indicators = indicators
        self.errors = errors

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return f"""
        <b>Indicator A:</b> {self.indicators[1]:.3f}<br>
        <b>Indicator B:</b> {self.indicators[2]:.3f}"""

    def _repr_png_(self):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2))
        plt.boxplot(self.errors, whis=[5, 95],
                    showfliers=False, vert=False)
        plt.title('Error distribution')
        plt.tight_layout()
        # return fig -- returning the figure is not mandatory
```

Versions: *Python v3.6.4 | Jupyter Notebook v5.4.1 | IPython v6.2.1 | Matplotlib v2.2.2*

Comment: I'm confused about what the problem is. Are you calling any of the methods `_repr_html_` and `_repr_png_` at any point?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest these methods are called by [IPython to render your content](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display). That is also why pandas' dataframes look pretty. I actually want the output of the first image where the text comes before the plot. So there is no problem other that I'm trying to understand why this works and if it will work for others as well. I don't want to hand over a broken Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: But they produce an error, right? I get `'EOF in multi-line string'`.

Comment: They shouldn't do that. I've shortened the code for SO, so maybe an error sneaked in. I cannot find any, though. Interesting enough changing to `%matplotlib notebook` puts the plot first, even if I'm not calling `show()`. Therefore, it's most likely not intended. But why does it work in inline mode?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify something first - The plot was not generated because you returned a figure, but because you called the `plt.boxplot()` method. Simply running the following line in its own cell will auto-generate the plot inline without a call to plt.show()

```
plt.boxplot(errors, whis=[5, 95], showfliers=False, vert=False)
```

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398940/jupyter-shows-plot-without-plt-show) which basically states that this is the default behavior.

I've always included the line `%matplotlib inline` in my notebook near the imports not knowing that it was the default behavior. I believe changing that line to `%matplotlib notebook` will change this behavior and force you to call `plt.show()` and `plt.figure()` when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, I'm using `%matplotlib inline` and I don't need to return the figure. However, if I call the `show()` method the plot is not part of the final output, but part of the output between input and output (where stuff you print out goes). I'll edit my question